# Quasi-random sequence with discrete variables with differing number of levels

Tags: sampling, experiment-design, discrete-data, fractional-factorial, quasi-monte-carlo

My question is probably worded incorrectly but here it is:
I have (say) 3 discrete random variables:
x1: has 15 levels (uniform pdf for simplicity)
x2: has 3 levels (uniforms)
x3: has 4 levels (uniform)

I want to generate *n* samples in such a way that:

1. there are no repetitions of samples
2. as n --> 15x3x4 the entire "full factorial" sample is generated;
3. When generating (n+d) set of samples, the first n samples are the identical for any d

I tried to use Sobol quasi random sequence to generate this sample BUT I am not able to satisfy #1 above without retaining all prior points in memory and checking for duplicates. This is something I would like to avoid.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

if i have understood your question, then you might find my blog post on “how to do quasirandom fractional multi factorial sampling based on the sobol sequence.” useful.

http://extremelearning.com.au/a-probabilistic-approach-to-fractional-factorial-design/

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality 
statistical information in the form of questions & answers. Thus, we're wary of 
link-only answers, due to linkrot. Can you post a full citation & a summary of the 
information at the link, in case it goes dead?